# Dúdiva sobre o uso de "caso contrário" entre virgulas

Tags: ortografia

É correto sempre isolar a expressão "caso contrário" entre vírgulas? Também gostaria de saber se o mesmo vale para a expressão "por exemplo"?

PS: Minha dúvida não é em relação a conjunções, apenas a algumas expressões específicas e seu uso isolado por vírgulas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acredito que as regras que determinam o uso dar vírgula nesses dois casos são

- Separar orações coordenadas sindéticas iniciadas pelas conjunções adversativas, alternativas, conclusivas ou explicativas. Exemplo:

  Caso eu esteja com fome, eu peço uma pizza, caso contrário, continuo dormindo
- Isolar expressões explicativas, corretivas ou continuativas representadas por: isto é, por exemplo, ou seja, aliás, entre outras. Exemplo:

  Existe bons sites para aprender mais sobre programação, por exemplo, o StackOverflow

Então, sim sempre, a não ser, claro, que essas expressões iniciam a frase

[Fonte e mais informações](https://www.google.com.br/amp/s/m.portugues.uol.com.br/amp/gramatica/o-uso-virgula-seus-pre-requisitos-.html)